# BMS for 4s lithium cells

Tags: batteries, audio, battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

I need to design and build my own BMS for a project, but I'm not sure about a couple of things. The list of components that I would like to use with the links will be at the end.

I want to know if I need to use the battery manager since the BMS doesn't do balanced charging if it's needed in my case because I'm not so sure.

I also want the info of charge and other characteristic via I2C because I will print them on an LCD screen.

This is for an audio project so if there's some alternatives with less noise I'm open to suggestions.

I would like to know if I'm going to blow myself up or not by making the circuits with these constraints in mind.

MCU is the Arduino Due if needed.

I tried looking around on multiple websites to see how the pack normally charges but I can't find any good information and I asked the support team and they basically pasted the description of the battery pack.

- Battery pack: [Zeee 4S Lipo Battery 5200mAh 14.8V 120C](https://zeeebattery.com/collections/zeee-rc-car-lipo-battery/products/zeee-4s-lipo-battery-5200mah-14-8v-120c-ec5)
- BMS/Charger: [BQ24610](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24610.pdf)
- Battery manager: [BQ76925](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76925.pdf)

Comment: _I need to design and build my own BMS for a project_

Are you sure? Generally, a BMS is something that you buy ready made, not that you design. Unless you work for a company that will make 1000 of them.

_Yes I am I have the means and skills just not the understanding for multiple cells in series I’ve done one little lithium 3,7 V one before_

I wasn't questioning your skills. I was questioning the wisdom.

Comment: Your proposal does not contain actual cell balancing which is needed in my opinion. You should state what average and peak current draw you expect. I support @DavideAndrea question why you think you need to design your own. 4S chargers with balancing and 4S packs of that size as well as 4S BMS boards are widely available. Unless you "want"  to design your own. If so, I'd look for a charging IC with I2C as well, and maybe a mating charge counter with I2C.